# How to reduce the padding of the labels in an ExtJS FormPanel?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, extjs

I'm trying to **reduce the padding** between the fields of my ExtJS form.

I am able to change the style of the **field data** with the style tag in the Items collection like this:

[image]

```
//form right
var simple_form_right = new Ext.FormPanel({
    frame:true,
    labelWidth: 90,
    labelAlign: 'right',
    title: 'Orderer Information',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0 0',
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    autoScroll: true,
    itemCls: 'form_row',
    defaultType: 'displayfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Customer Type',
            name: 'customerType',
            style: 'padding:0px;font-size:7pt',
            labelStyle: 'padding:0px',
            allowBlank: false,
            value: 'Company'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Company',
            name: 'company',
            value: 'The Ordering Company Inc.'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName',
            value: 'Smith'
        }, {
        ...
```

**But how do I access the style of the label as well, something like styleLabel or labelStyle, etc.?**

Comment: Oh please... don't post code samples as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`labelPad`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Form.html#cfg-Ext.form.FormPanel-labelPad) which defaults to 5px apparently, and [`labelStyle`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-labelStyle) if you need more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `labelStyle` property available for form fields.
Here is an example:

```
items: [{
   fieldLabel: 'Company',
   name: 'company',
   labelStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px;'
}]
```